# svn: warning: W170000 on OSX 10.11 El Capitan with two svn versions

Tags: macos, svn

After an update to Mac OSX 10.11 El Capitan the command

```
/usr/bin/svn info  ssh://svn@SERVER.COM///var/svn/repos/project/XYZ --force-interactive
```

returns:

```
svn: warning: W170000: Unrecognized URL scheme for 'ssh://svn@SERVER.COM/var/svn/repos/project/XYZ'
```

The installed version is:

```
/usr/bin/svn --version
svn, version 1.7.20 (r1667490)
   compiled Oct  5 2015, 14:53:48

Copyright (C) 2014 The Apache Software Foundation.
This software consists of contributions made by many people; see the NOTICE
file for more information.
Subversion is open source software, see http://subversion.apache.org/

The following repository access (RA) modules are available:

* ra_neon : Module for accessing a repository via WebDAV protocol using Neon.
  - handles 'http' scheme
  - handles 'https' scheme
* ra_svn : Module for accessing a repository using the svn network protocol.
  - handles 'svn' scheme
* ra_local : Module for accessing a repository on local disk.
  - handles 'file' scheme
* ra_serf : Module for accessing a repository via WebDAV protocol using serf.
  - handles 'http' scheme
  - handles 'https' scheme
```

After some reading I found out the ra_svn needs the SASL Support.
So I installed a second SVN with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/index_de.html) with

```
brew install svn
```

It is installed in

```
/usr/local/bin/svn
```

The version is:

```
/usr/local/bin/svn --version
svn, version 1.9.2 (r1703836)
   compiled Nov 15 2015, 11:43:08 on x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0

Copyright (C) 2015 The Apache Software Foundation.
This software consists of contributions made by many people;
see the NOTICE file for more information.
Subversion is open source software, see http://subversion.apache.org/

The following repository access (RA) modules are available:

* ra_svn : Module for accessing a repository using the svn network protocol.
  - with Cyrus SASL authentication
  - handles 'svn' scheme
* ra_local : Module for accessing a repository on local disk.
  - handles 'file' scheme
* ra_serf : Module for accessing a repository via WebDAV protocol using serf.
  - using serf 1.3.8
  - handles 'http' scheme
  - handles 'https' scheme

The following authentication credential caches are available:

* Plaintext cache in /Users/USERNAME/.subversion
* Mac OS X Keychain
```

But the call

```
/usr/local/bin/svn info  ssh://svn@SERVER.COM///var/svn/repos/project/XYZ --force-interactive
```

still returns:

```
svn: warning: W170000: Unrecognized URL scheme for 'ssh://svn@SERVER.COM/var/svn/repos/project/XYZ'
```

Whats wrong?

Are the repository access (RA) modules stored in a library path (like plugins) and the wrong ones are use when I call /usr/local/bin/svn instead of /usr/bin/svn ?

Need some ideas, what to try. Thanks.

Comment: I allso tried http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63946/disabling-usr-bin-svn-to-use-brew-installed-svn without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL scheme should be `svn+ssh` for access Subversion repository over ssh. I.e.

```
/usr/local/bin/svn info  svn+ssh://svn@SERVER.COM///var/svn/repos/project/XYZ --force-interactive
```

Comment: I changed it that way, but the result is exactly the same. And by the way it worked about two years before the update. But Thanks @Ivan Zhakov for the idea.

Comment: @smartmeta I made a typo in command line in my answer. Try `/usr/local/bin/svn info svn+ssh://svn@SERVER.COM///var/svn/repos/project/XYZ --force-interactive`

Comment: Thanks @Ivan Zhakov thats it. Not it works again! What was wrong before?

Comment: You had classic with two errors: one even proper fix doesn't the problem. First problem was using incorrect protocol: `ssh` instead of `svn+ssh`. Other problem that I've used path to stock installation of Subversion (`/usr/bin/svn` instead of `/usr/local/bin/`) which cause to Subversion 1.7.20.